# SyntaxNet Bazel build failed: gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-h'

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet

Trying to install SyntaxNet on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, build fails with gcc unrecognized command line option '-h'.
Searched gcc documentation and there seems to be no such command line option.
Have anybody seen this?

```
sudo /home/user/bin/bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names --spawn_strategy=standalone --genrule_strategy=standalone \ 
    syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
INFO: Found 65 targets and 12 test targets...
ERROR: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/1a72b3057373bad6ae8a8f20db5423d4/external/re2/BUILD:9:1: Linking of rule '@re2//:re2' failed: gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -shared -o bazel-out/local-opt/bin/external/re2/libre2.so -pthread -no-canonical-prefixes -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -pass-exit-codes '-Wl,--build-id=md5' '-Wl,--hash-style=gnu' ... (remaining 3 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-h'
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.857s, Critical Path: 0.45s
```

Comment: Can you run bazel with -s at the end so we can see the full command line that it's failing on? That might help narrow down what's going wrong.